# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException using selenium in python 3.7

Tags: selenium, xpath, python-3.7

I am trying to use selenium to automate the process from open a specific website to log in to search for particular articles. Few of the steps I could do it but facing error in 'sign in' step.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
base = 'https://www.wsj.com'
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=cybersecurity&min-date=2018/04/01&max-date=2019/03/31&isAdvanced=true&daysback=90d&andor=AND&sort=date-desc&source=wsjarticle,wsjpro&page=1'

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('editions-select').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('na,us').click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('**#&^&@$@#$')
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('@#@$%%**')
browser.find_element_by_id('basic-login').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('masthead-container').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput').send_keys('cybersecurity')
browser.find_element_by_name('ADVANCED SEARCH').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131783').send_keys('2018/04/01')
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131784').send_keys('2019/03/31')
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjblogs').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjvideo').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('interactivemedia').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('sitesearch').click()
```

The code is working till this line:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('na,us').click()
```

But after that it is showing error in this line:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]").click()
```

The error message says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

What should I do to make it work? What is the problem?

Comment: the locators you have here don't appear on the website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

botton_to_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable, ((By.XPATH,"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]")))
botton_to_click.click()
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: `contains(.,'Sign In')` is perfect where as I feel `contains(text(),'Sign In')` is not optimized.

Comment: Not working. Showing error in line button_to_click.click() Error is: 
AttributeError: 'element_to_be_clickable' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: No. Error: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya Sorry I'm not on PC so it's hard to fix typoes... one moment I fixed it I am sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: Again error. Showing error in line  botton_to_click() Error is AttributeError: 'element_to_be_clickable' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195326/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-piyush-ghasiya).